# reporting_system_updates table is getting large

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1.9, table, log-cleaning

On our webshop (running community 2.1.9) we have a table called reporting_system_updates and it is allready over 300Mb in size.
Can I safely truncate this table?

Answer (score 4):

***(TLDR) Simple/Short Answer:***

Here's a screenshot of the "Official" response I received - from the New Relic Support team:

[image]

In other words, you can safely delete data in the `reporting_system_updates` table using either of the following SQLs:

```
// The "I'm All In" Approach
truncate table reporting_system_updates ;

// The "Play It Safe(r)" Approach
delete from reporting_system_updates where type in ( 'moduleEnabled' , 'moduleInstalled' , 'moduleUninstalled' ) ;
```

***(Much) Longer Answer:***

Looking at the New Relic cron (vendor/magento/module-new-relic-reporting/etc/crontab.xml) which is currently scheduled to run every 2 minutes:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">
    <group id="default">
        <job name="magento_newrelicreporting_cron" instance="Magento\NewRelicReporting\Model\Cron" method="runCron">
            <schedule>*/2 * * * *</schedule>
        </job>
    </group>
</config>
```

The cron invokes the following `runCron()` method within `vendor/magento/module-new-relic-reporting/Model/Cron.php`

[image]

Code of interest in the above snippet is:

```
$this->reportModulesInfo->report();
```

Which takes us to `vendor/magento/module-new-relic-reporting/Model/Cron/ReportModulesInfo.php`

[image]
Code of interest in the above snippet is:

```
$moduleData = $this->collect->getModuleData();
```

Which takes us to `vendor/magento/module-new-relic-reporting/Model/Module/Collect.php`

[image]
Code of interest in the above snippet is:

```
$configModules = $this->getAllModules();
```

Which takes us to `vendor/magento/module-new-relic-reporting/Model/Module/Collect.php`

[image]
Code of interest in the above snippet is:

```
return $this->fullModuleList->getAll();
```

Which takes us to `vendor/magento/framework/Module/FullModuleList.php`

[image]
Code of interest in the above snippet is:

```
$this->data = $this->loader->load();
```

Which takes us to `vendor/magento/framework/Module/ModuleList/Loader.php`

[image]

Once all the requisite Module Information is sourced in `vendor/magento/module-new-relic-reporting/Model/Cron/ReportModulesInfo.php` the processor stores that module data in the DB `tablereporting_system_updates`

```
                /** @var \Magento\NewRelicReporting\Model\System $systemModel */
                $systemModel = $this->systemFactory->create();
                $systemModel->setData($modelData);
                $systemModel->save();
```

Your Typical Magento Installation has ~ 150 - 300 modules installed.

The New Relic cron is setup to be run every 2 minutes:

[image]

In other words, the `reporting_system_updates` table will see ~150 - 300 new DB rows inserted into it every 2 minutes ... Extrapolate that and you're looking at roughly ~110K - 220K junk records / day.

Comment: You are my hero.  Bravo sir!  This helped me solve a really big WTF almost instantly.

Comment: Glad I could help @DAvid